# Speakers are not working while headphones are working on my Dell Inspiron 17 5000 Series laptop

Tags: sound, dell, headphones, inspiron, speakers

Speakers are not working while headphones are working on my Dell Inspiron 17 5000 Series laptop. Can you please help me to solve the problem?

This is the link to my alsa-info script: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=9f7b5ddb1f41ce0bc96c7bcae29202a994355cd3

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could we have more information? Do these headphones use USB or a 3.5 audio jack? Are the speakers internally installed on the laptop or are they external and the use USB/3.5 jack?

Comment: Dear Michael, thank you very much for your interest! These headphones use a 3.5 audio jack and the speakers are internally installed on the laptop. If you have any other question, do not hesitate to ask!

Comment: What audio device is selected in the sound settings under the Output tab? It should say something like "Analogue Output"

Comment: It says "Analogue Output Built-in Audio". It is the only option that I am given to choose from the audio devices in the sound settings under the Output tab. @MichaelLindman

Comment: What version of Ubuntu you're using? And is it a Ubuntu pre-installed laptop? Can you run the [alsa-info script](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo) and paste the link [back to your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/598694/edit)? Thanks

Comment: Dear @P.-H.Lin, thank you very much for your interest! I am sorry for my slow response, I was away for a couple of days. It is ubuntu 12.04 LTS version on a Ubuntu pre-installed laptop. I believe that this should be the link to my alsa-info script: file:///tmp/alsa-info.txt.5L2Vlz0Hg1 If not, or if there is anything esle, I can do, do not hesitate to tell! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @StefanMartinić, we can't download your alsa-info file, please upload it by using the script itself, thanks

Comment: Dear @P.-H.Lin I am very sorry for doing it wrongly. I beleive that this now should be the link for the script: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=9f7b5ddb1f41ce0bc96c7bcae29202a994355cd3

Answer (score 0):

can you navigate to Settings -> Sound and check outputs there? 
I often have them set to headphones (after plugging them in) and it doesn't switch back on disconnect. Manually reselecting output device work, thoguh. 
Just select headphones and then normal speakers again and it should work fine.